# How to repeatedly mark all rows after threshold within timeframe with same unique identifier?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with tens of thousands of rows.

I want to mark every row where column **Transaction** reaches or exceeds a threshold (say, 100), and then every row following that happens within 20 hours after and has the same **UniqueID** as the row that reached the threshold.
It needs to be able to do this every time the threshold is reached for each **UniqueID**.
If it fulfills the conditions, mark it with `FR`, otherwise `NR`.

Essentially, I have 3 relevant columns, and want to add a fourth with categorical data, named Flagged.

```
library(lubridate)
UniqueID <- c(214123, 214123, 214123, 214123, 987556, 987556, 987556, 987556, 987556)

datetime <- ymd_hms("2021-12-5 21:16:00", "2021-12-6 10:16:00", "2021-12-8 08:16:00", "2021-12-30 01:26:00", "2021-12-5 10:33:00", "2021-12-6 08:16:00", "2021-12-6 13:26:00", "2022-01-6 13:26:00", "2022-01-6 13:26:00")

Transactions <- c(100, 30, 20, 110, 30, 105, 50, 20, 140)

df <- data.frame(UniqueID, datetime, Transactions)

df
```

`UniqueID`: identifiers that are unique for each user

`datetime`: when the transaction occurs

`Transactions`: the amount of the transaction

In the above example, rows 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9 should be marked `FR` whereas the others are `NR`. Ultimately, it should look like:

```
UniqueID <- c(214123, 214123, 214123, 214123, 987556, 987556, 987556, 987556, 987556)

datetime <- ymd_hms("2021-12-5 21:16:00", "2021-12-6 10:16:00", "2021-12-8 08:16:00", "2021-12-30 01:26:00", "2021-12-5 10:33:00", "2021-12-6 08:16:00", "2021-12-6 13:26:00", "2022-01-6 13:26:00", "2022-01-6 13:26:00")

Transactions <- c(100, 30, 20, 110, 30, 105, 50, 20, 140)

Flagged <- c("FR", "FR", "NR", "FR", "NR", "FR", "FR", "NR", "FR")

df <- data.frame(UniqueID, datetime, Transactions, Flagged)

df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # fill
df %>%
  group_by(UniqueID) %>%
  mutate(last100 = if_else(Transactions >= 100, datetime, datetime[NA])) %>%
  fill(last100) %>%
  mutate(Flagged = coalesce(if_else(difftime(datetime, last100, units = "hours") <= 20, "FR", "NR"), "NR")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-last100)
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   UniqueID datetime            Transactions Flagged
#      <dbl> <dttm>                     <dbl> <chr>  
# 1   214123 2021-12-05 21:16:00          100 FR     
# 2   214123 2021-12-06 10:16:00           30 FR     
# 3   214123 2021-12-08 08:16:00           20 NR     
# 4   214123 2021-12-30 01:26:00          110 FR     
# 5   987556 2021-12-05 10:33:00           30 NA     
# 6   987556 2021-12-06 08:16:00          105 FR     
# 7   987556 2021-12-06 13:26:00           50 FR     
# 8   987556 2022-01-06 13:26:00           20 NR     
# 9   987556 2022-01-06 13:26:00          140 FR
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[Transactions >= 100, last100 := datetime
  ][, last100 := nafill(last100, type = "locf"), by = .(UniqueID)
  ][, Flagged := fcoalesce(
     fifelse(difftime(datetime, last100, units = "hours") <= 20,
             "FR", "NR"),
     "NR")
  ][, last100 := NULL]
#    UniqueID            datetime Transactions Flagged
#       <num>              <POSc>        <num>  <char>
# 1:   214123 2021-12-05 21:16:00          100      FR
# 2:   214123 2021-12-06 10:16:00           30      FR
# 3:   214123 2021-12-08 08:16:00           20      NR
# 4:   214123 2021-12-30 01:26:00          110      FR
# 5:   987556 2021-12-05 10:33:00           30      NR
# 6:   987556 2021-12-06 08:16:00          105      FR
# 7:   987556 2021-12-06 13:26:00           50      FR
# 8:   987556 2022-01-06 13:26:00           20      NR
# 9:   987556 2022-01-06 13:26:00          140      FR
```

Comment: on a scale of 1-10, 1 being absolute beginner, 5 average, and 10 expert of experts
how hard of a question would you rank this for data analysts?

Comment: That's a _horrible_ question, @BarelySapeintOrangutan! ;-) Okay, well ... because much of what I do is as a statistician, so I'll give you a range ... 5-7 perhaps.

Comment: I ask horrible questions so one day I might not ask horrible questions
thanks for the help!

Comment: I know this is forever after
but can you explain what causes/the purpose of, "NA" in 
mutate(Flagged = coalesce(if_else(difftime(datetime, last100, units = "hours") <= 20, "FR", "NR"), "NA"))
and why NA isn't included in the data.table method?
to be clear, this still accomplishes the intended goal, but I can't figure out why some are NA rather than NR

Comment: Huh ... I suspect it was a typo @BarelySapeintOrangutan, see my edit (changed from `"NA"` to `"NR"`).